# List of anime referenced in Bakuman

Tags: bakuman

Can anybody give me a complete reference to all anime whose titles, artists and/or lines were referenced in the Bakuman series? It would also be great if you could let me know when they were mentioned. External sources will be appreciated too.

Comment: Are you asking about *only real* anime, like *Naruto* and *One Piece*, or are you asking about *all* anime, including *Otter 11* and *Crow*?

Comment: Yes the real animes! The ones i can read and watch!@Nolonar

Comment: The TV Tropes [page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/Bakuman) for Bakuman has a sizable list of references under the "Shout-Out" entry, many with links to the specific instance. Many of the referenced anime/manga hail from *Shonen Jump,* including *Death Note,* *Dragon Ball,* and *One Piece.* A complete reference chart may be difficult to find or compile without significant effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Manga Bakuman has references to several other works from time to time

- One Piece
- Bleach
- Naruto
- DragonBall
- Touch
- To Love ru
- Enigma
- Sakigake Otokojuku
- Kimi ni Todoke
- Death Note
- Gintama
- Fist of the North Star
- Star of the Giants
- Ai and Makoto
- Doraemon
- Slam Dunk
- Hunter X Hunter
- Ashita no Joe

There are some missing in the list I will add those once I find out

Answer (score 5):

- To Love Ru (A discussion between the protagonists and fellow mangakas about this ecchi manga and how it was targeted at boys)
- Death Note (Mentioned while talking about successful manga)
- Naruto by Masashi Kishimoto
- One Piece by Eiichiro Oda
- Bleach by Tite Kubo
- Slam Dunk: A manga about basketball (brought up when the protagonists are talking about their favourite manga)
- Ashita no Joe: A manga about boxing (brought up when the protagonists are  talking about their inspiration/their favourite manga),
- Hunter x Hunter
- Dragon Ball Z (Name is brought up from time to time)

They may have referenced a few other anime but these are the ones that came up the most.

Answer (score 3):

- Ashita no Joe
- One Piece
- Bleach
- Naruto
- Dragon Ball
- Gintama
- Beet the Vandel Buster
- Star of the Giants
- Death Note
- The Qualifications of a Man (Ikki Kajiwara)
- Father's Soul / Soul of the Father (Kaizuka Hiroshi)
- KochiKame
- Hikaru no Go
- Kamen Rider
- Fist of the North Star
- Hunter X Hunter
- Flower Angel TenTen
- Beelzebub
- Yoroshiku Mechadock
- To Love Ru
- Nura: The Rise of the Yokai Clan / Nurarihyon
- Sakigake!! Otokojuku
- Dr. Slump
- Gatchaman (1972)
- Doraemon
- Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo
- Dai's Big Adventure (Dragon Quest)
- Rurouni Kenshin
- Touch
- Ai to Makoto
- Kimi n Todoke
- Boys Over Flowers
- Nodame Cantabile
- Ichigo 100%
- Anedoki
- Hatsukoi Limited
- Kikaider (Shotaro Ishinomori)
- Secret Squad Goranger
- Transforming Ninja Arashi
- Robot Cop
- Lupin the 3rd
- Phoenix (Osamu Tezuka)
- The Rose of Versailles
- Glass Mask
- Barefoot Gen
- Demonic Detective Neuro Nougami
- Toriko
- Yu-Gi-Oh!